# Compact form for font interferes with vertical-alignment

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, text-alignment

I have this code:

```
li
{
   width: 200px; height: 22px; overflow: hidden;
   float: left;

   line-height: 22px; letter-spacing: -1px;
   font-weight: 400; font-size: 14px; font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
   text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

I noticed that if I write all the font properties separated, then I'll have my text in the li box vertical-aligned middle.

```
font: 400 14px "Helvetica Neue";
```

Else, if I use the compact form, the text is vertical-aligned top.

I'd like to understand why this happens.

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Pq2yh/)**

CSS shorthand peoperties described as

```
selector {  
    font: font-style font-variant font-weight font-size/line-height font-family;  
}
```

1) In your case: `font: 400 14px "Helvetica Neue";`
here you not defining any line height hence its taking default line height and Text seems to be vertically aligned top

2) if you use `font: 400 14px/22px "Helvetica Neue";`
here you are defining line height - 22px and this will be vertically middle aligned

**Sidenote**

vertical align middle works because height of LI = line height

**[Article URL](http://www.impressivewebs.com/a-primer-on-the-css-font-shorthand-property/)**

Comment: Thank you a lot, very clear. I didn't know the "/line-height" property!

Comment: No Probs :) Good Luck Hope it helps!